# Encryption Algorithm from PHP to Ruby (Vignere variant)

Tags: php, ruby, code-translation

I am a bit stuck with this. I have to interface with an api that uses a version of an encryption algorithm that they seem to have ripped from Typo3 written by Ari Kuorikoski.

I need to create a ruby lib to interface with their api, so have to port their algorithm into ruby, and I am a bit out of my depth when it comes to encryption.

This is the code:

```
private function keyED($txt) { 
$encrypt_key = md5($this->encrypt_key); 
$ctr=0; 
$tmp = ""; 
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($txt);$i++) { 
   if ($ctr==strlen($encrypt_key)) $ctr=0; 
   $tmp.= substr($txt,$i,1) ^ substr($encrypt_key,$ctr,1); 
   $ctr++; 
} 
return $tmp; 
} 

private function encrypt($txt){ 
srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
$encrypt_key = md5(rand(0,32000)); 
$ctr=0; 
$tmp = ""; 
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($txt);$i++){ 
   if ($ctr==strlen($encrypt_key)) $ctr=0; 
   $tmp.= substr($encrypt_key,$ctr,1) . 
       (substr($txt,$i,1) ^ substr($encrypt_key,$ctr,1)); 
   $ctr++; 
} 
return base64_encode($this->keyED($tmp)); 
}
```

The part that has me stumped is this, I have to write it for ruby 1.8.6 as that's the server that it will be on. And there's no XOR for strings. Not that I would understand it if there was.

Any help, pointers, ideas would be much much appreciated.

Addendum:

I realize, I didn't put any code up, the only difficulty is actually the xor problem, but here is my code so far:

```
def xor(s1,s2)
        if s2.empty? then
            return s1
        else
            a1 = s1.unpack("c*")
            a2 = s2.unpack("c*")
            a2 *= 2 while a2.length < a1.length
            return a1.zip(a2).collect {|c1,c2| c1 ^ c2}.pack("c*")
        end
    end
    def keyED(str)
        encrypt_key = Digest::MD5.digest(@key)
        ctr = 0
        tmp = ''
        for i in 0...str.length do
             ctr = 0 if ctr == encrypt_key.length
             tmp << xor(str.slice(i,1), encrypt_key.slice(ctr,1)).to_s
            ctr = ctr + 1
        end
        return tmp
    end

    # === Ported Code
    # This code was ported from Ari's Typo 3 Session Encryption
    def encrypt(str)
        encrypt_key = Digest::MD5.digest(rand(32000).to_s)
        ctr = 0
        tmp = ''
        for i in 0...str.length do
            ctr=0 if ctr==encrypt_key.length 
            tmp << encrypt_key.slice(ctr,1) << xor(str.slice(i,1), encrypt_key.slice(ctr,1))
            ctr = ctr + 1
        end
        return Base64.encode64(keyED(tmp))
    end
    def decrypt(str)
        txt = keyED(str)
        tmp = ''
        for i in 0...txt.length do 
            md = txt.slice(i,1)
            i = i + 1
            tmp << xor(txt.slice(i,1),md)
        end
        puts "Decrypte string:#{Base64.decode64(tmp)}EOSTRING"
    end
```

Comment: One thing I did find, is that you can get a Fixnum by trying str[i] and encrypt_key[ctr], and perform an xor on those...That didn't work either, but I may have fudged it elsewhere in the code.

Comment: As an update, I manages to fix the problem by creating a tokenmaker.php file with the working php functions, and calling it using net/http. I hate doing it this way, but I am on a schedule. I would really really love to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Erik Veenstra](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/236609):

```
class String
  def xor(other)
    if other.empty?
      self
    else
      a1        = self.unpack("c*")
      a2        = other.unpack("c*")
      a2 *= 2   while a2.length < a1.length
      a1.zip(a2).collect{|c1,c2| c1^c2}.pack("c*")
    end
  end
end
```

Then your code becomes

```
tmp << str.slice(i,1).xor(encrypt_key.slice(i,1))
```

An alternate implementation of `String#xor`, as suggested by [jolierouge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249900/jolierouge) and [David Garamond](http://oldrcrs.rubypal.com/rcr/show/222):

```
class String
  def xor(other)
    raise ArgumentError, "Can't bitwise-XOR a String with a non-String" unless other.kind_of? String
    raise ArgumentError, "Can't bitwise-XOR strings of different length" unless self.length == other.length
    (0..self.length-1).collect { |i| self[i] ^ other[i] }.pack("C*")
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried a variant of this, the issue is, I don't have the knowledge to explain why it doesn't work int the same way the the PHP xor on a string works.

I need it to do exactly what it's doing in the PHP function, without variation. I have written a decrypt function, ported also from the php, I should be able to put a string in, and get that same string out.

Comment: Or something else could be wrong, I'll update the ruby source thus far.

Comment: I'll post the update and working source for others to peruse.

Answer (score 0):

*Editor's Note: The final working code was moved from the question to its own answer.*

Final working source, based on James helpful answer, major props! And to David Garamound.

```
def xor(s1,s2)
    raise ArgumentError, "Can't bitwise-XOR a String with a non-String" unless s2.kind_of? String
    raise ArgumentError, "Can't bitwise-XOR strings of different length" unless s1.length == s2.length
    (0..s1.length-1).collect { |i| s1[i] ^ s2[i] }.pack("C*")
end

def keyED(txt,key)
    ctr,tmp = 0,''
    key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(key)
    for i in 0...txt.length do
        ctr = 0 if ctr == key.length
        str = xor(txt.slice(i,1),key.slice(ctr,1))
        tmp << str
        ctr = ctr + 1
    end

    return tmp
end
def encrypt(txt,key)
    ctr,tmp = 0,''
    ekey = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand(32000).to_s)
    for i in 0...txt.length do
        ctr = 0 if ctr == ekey.length
        str = xor(txt.slice(i,1), ekey.slice(ctr,1))
        tmp << ekey.slice(ctr,1) << str
        ctr = ctr + 1
    end
    return Base64.encode64(keyED(tmp,key))
end
```